# Efficiently returning an instance of the List interface when you want uniqueness in Java

Tags: java, list, collections, unique

I have an interface that I want to implement that contains the following method signature:

```
/** 
 * Return an umodifiable ordered collection
 */
public List<String> getItems();
```

In my particular implementation I need the items to be unique.  What is the best way to implement this?

I have considered

```
private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> getItems(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(items);
}
public void addItem(String s){
    // Inefficient -- has to scan entire list for contains
    if (!items.contains(s)) items.add(s);
}
```

And

```
private LinkedHashSet<String> items = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
public List<String> getItems(){
    // Inefficient -- has to copy the list
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList(items));
}
public void addItem(String s){
    items.add(s);
}
```

I'd really like LinkedHashSet to implement the List interface so I could return it directly from my second approach.  Is there a work around or better solution?

Comment: One (potentially rubbish) way is to create both a set and a list inside your method, but only return the list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the person that was leading me down this path deleted their answer, I'll submit it as an answer on my own.  (Sorry, now that your answer is deleted, I don't know who you were.)

The interface could be changed to

```
/** 
 * Return an umodifiable ordered collection
 */
Collection<String> getItems();
```

And then the implementation could use a LinkedHashSet with no problem:

```
private LinkedHashSet<String> items = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
public Collection<String> getItems(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(items);
}
public void addItem(String s){
    items.add(s);
}
```

This would require that the interface is somewhere that can be changed (not third party), all classes that implement it can can similarly be tracked down and changed, and that places that call it don't use List features like `get(int i)`.

Answer (score 3):

Combine your approaches:

```
private Set<String> itemSet = new HashSet<String>();
private List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getItems() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(itemList);
}

public addItem(String s) {
    if (itemSet.add(s)) {
        itemList.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BheshGurung: Oh, I haven't understood your first comment right. After reading it again, (and your explanation now) it totally makes sense. I'll edit my answer in favor of the more efficient code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your unmodifiability constraints, this could be straightforward with the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) library.  Guava's `ImmutableSet` class has an `asList()` view that lets you view an `ImmutableSet` as an `ImmutableList`.  `asList()` takes O(1) time and the returned `List` supports constant-time random access.